# URL rewriting in Web.Config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to remove a part of URL from my current URL:
Example:
Current URL: https://www.example.com/parameter1/parameter2
I want to remove **parameter1** from the above URL redirect to :
"https://www.example.com/parameter2"

I want to write this code in Web.release.config.

Please suggest.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Web.config doesn't have anything that let's you do a redirect. It's not like .htaccess, if you're coming from *nix world and think it's the IIS equivalent.

Comment: In your example, how would you then differentiate an actual request to `https://www.example.com/foo` vs the one that was "redirected"? If this were MVC (tagged as such), this (should) be done in your route config without the need for "redirects".

Comment: Actually this is URL rewriting. It should be of type:
<rule name="something some name" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?partofwebsitename.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.websiteurl.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>

Comment: i just need to remove parameter1 from my URL.

Comment: To be more specific when an user hits "https://www.example.com/parameter1/parameter2" he should be redirected to "https://www.example.com/parameter2".
parameter2 can be anything like parameter3, xyz, abc, etc. but parameter1 is constant and it should be removed when the user hits it.

Comment: Does your server have the URL rewriting module installed?

Comment: @ChrisPratt you can create rewrite rules in the web.config [as explained here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). Useful for helping with canonical URLs (enforcing lowercase URLs, ensure trailing slashes, removing `default.aspx`, etc).